# How to list snaps with their confinement?

Tags: snap

`snap list` shows all snaps, but does not list the confinement model.  Is it possible to list all snaps with their info and confinement?

Comment: With which of the confinement was the snap installed?  strict, classic or devmode?  See:  [Snap Confinement](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement/6233)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `snap list` for getting a list of all snaps and then run `snap info --verbose` on them [to get the confinement level](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snap-confinement).

For doing that with all installed snaps, you can use a few pipes:

```bash
snap list | tail -n +2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -i bash -c 'echo -n "{} = " && snap info --verbose {} | grep confinement  | rev | cut -d" " -f1  |rev'
```

The above command does the following:

- `snap list` lists installed snaps
- `tail -n +2` removes the header so you only have actual snaps
- `cut -d' ' -f1` only keeps the names of the snaps
- `args -i bash -c '<cmd> {}'` runs the command `<cmd>` for each argument while replacing `{}` with the argument

  - So, for each snap, it runs the command
    `echo -n "{} = " && snap info --verbose {}|grep confinement|rev|cut -d" " -f1|rev`
    but uses the snap name instead of `{}`
  - `echo -n "{} = "` just prints the name of the snap followed by `=` (and spaces) without a newline. This makes sure you know which snap belongs to which confinement
  - `snap info --verbose {}|grep confinement|rev|cut -d" " -f1|rev` prints the confinement of the given snap

    - `snap info --verbose` shows information about your snap including one line for the confinement
    - `grep confinement` gives you the line with the confinement
    - `rev|cut -d" " -f1|rev` [gets the last word of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727211/10871900) which contains the confinement

Alternatively, you can do

```bash
snap list | tail -n +2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs snap info --verbose | grep --color=never -E 'name|confinement'
```

This does the following:

- `snap list | tail -n +2 | cut -d' ' -f1` gets all snap names, it's the same as before
- `xargs snap info --verbose` runs `snap info --verbose` for each snap
- `grep --color=never -E 'name|confinement'` gets all lines [containing `name` or `confinement`](https://superuser.com/a/143243/1079262) without displaying colors

Answer (score 3):

Hard to find online. Looks like is not an official way to do it yet.

Some developers have shared how to do it with a shell script in the snapcraft forum.

You can take a look here:
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/reliable-way-of-detecting-snap-confinement-mode/8896

Otherwise, I've found it is actually shown in the "snap list" response in the notes column. As in here:

[image]

Just to know about defaults, Snap man page states about the installation command:

"The install command installs the named snaps in the system.
With no further options, the snaps are installed tracking the stable channel, with **strict** security confinement."